# Can I encrypt web.config with a custom protection provider who's assembly is not in the GAC?

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, encryption, web-config

I have written a custom protected configuration provider for my web.config.

When I try to encrypt my web.config with it I get the following error from aspnet_iisreg

> aspnet_regiis.exe -pef appSettings . -prov CustomProvider (This is running in my MSBuild)
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'MyCustomProviderNamespace' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

After checking with the Fusion log, I confirm it is checking both the GAC, and 'C:/WINNT/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/' (the location of aspnet_iisreg). But it cannot find the provider.

I do not want to move my component into the GAC, I want to leave the custom assembly in my ApplicationBase to copy around to various servers without having to pull/push from the GAC.

Here is my provider configuration in the web.config.

```
<configProtectedData>
  <providers>
    <add name="CustomProvider"
         type="MyCustomProviderNamespace.MyCustomProviderClass,
         MyCustomProviderNamespace" />
  </providers>
</configProtectedData>
```

I want aspnet_iisreg to check my ApplicationBase Bin folder for this assembly. Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bit dirty, what I ended up doing was adding the DLL doing the encryption to the GAC of the build machine. This encrypted the config okay.

When deploying the solution, I copied the Dll into the ApplicationBase, the application was able to decrypt it succesfully.